# Badges for other sites in profile show icon of current site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When looking at the Account section of my profile, it shows Stack Exchange sites I have accounts on, along with my rep for each and badges I have earned on each. The badge icons, though, are the same as the badge icon of the SE site I'm currently viewing though.

For example, looking at the Accounts section of my Academia profile:

[image: Academia]

vs looking at the same Account section of my Home Improvement profile:

[image: Home improvement]

Badges for all sites in my Academia profile show the graduation cap icon, while in my Home Improvement profile they all show the Phillips-screw-head icon. It seems that the icons for each site should be specific for that site - so my Home Improvement badges would be the screw-head icons, regardless from which site I'm viewing my profile, and my Academia badges would be graduation caps.

Comment: I don't think it is a bug, but rather status-by-design to avoid HTTP requests to other sites to load their bronze, silver and gold badge versions.

Comment: @Tom, sounds legit. But still, it would be cool to have the badges in their site specific theme!

Comment: Strange! I see discs / filled circles any-where I go, from where-ever I see.